# how do decimals work through binary?

Tags: binary, decimal

Binary is 1 and 0, so how do we get decimals, and how are they accurate? I'm asking because I remember someone telling me that floats and doubles calculate differently, so that can mess up calculations.  Also, what are the differences between the two?

Comment: Google is your friend, so why not try google?

Comment: Way too broad sadly. Google "binary floating point", and set aside a not inconsiderable amount of time to grasp the contents. It's very clever stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, think about just integers, like 0, 1, 2, ...

There are different ways to write them, like I, II, III, IV, V, VI, ... (assuming, like the Romans, that 0 was not a number)
or 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 9, 10, 11 ... the ways the Indian ancients and Arabs taught us, making use of place notations, a symbol for zero, and our ten fingers.

Notice the numbers are the same. There are just different ways of writing them.

Suppose you an intelligent horse, with only two fingers on your "hands".
You could count like this: 0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, ...

Well, computers are like horses (but less intelligent) and they count like that.

The way you write them is important, because it can make arithmetic easy.
(Just try multiplying in roman numerals.)

---

To make negatives, there is a trick making use of one of the bits.

Don't worry about floating point. That is just a way of faking really big and small numbers, by using integers.